# How to implement antialiasing in DirectShow?

Tags: winapi, video, directshow, direct3d9

My project uses DirectShow to capture camera input and implement preview functionality. However, I am encountering a problem with noticeable aliasing in the camera preview. Therefore, I am considering incorporating antialiasing into my project using VMR9 and Direct3D. The idea is to enable antialiasing in Direct3D while allowing VMR9 to handle the overall rendering process. I'm not sure if my approach is feasible, or if you have any better suggestions to share. Thank you.

Currently, the Anti-Aliasing has not been successfully implemented.

Comment: I 'd say you use Media foundation.

Comment: You could try to set the `D3DRS_MULTISAMPLEANTIALIAS` render state to `TRUE` to enable full-scene antialiasing.Refer to the Doc:[Full-Scene Antialiasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/full-scene-antialiasing)

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Of course, Media Foundation is a good idea.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I have tried to use the method you mentioned, the result is not obvious.

Comment: I have solved this problem by using EVR as the renderer.